# Troubles using .net ScriptManager for Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to use ScriptManager in .net Visual Web Developer 2010, but every time I run the website, an error message appears:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. (System couldn't find the specifyed file). Line 7:  </asp:Content> 

Line 8: <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server"> 
Line 9:      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/> 
Line 10:     <div> Line 11:     <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" selectedindex = "0" 
runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" hHeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent" AutoSize="None" FadeTransitions="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
```

I've instaled MS-F# tool expecting FSharp.Core file would be copyed and solve the problem, but nothing changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot register a ScriptManager in a ContentPage of a MasterPage. You should register it in the MasterPage and use a [ScriptManagerproxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) in your Contentpages:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

Comment: its worth, thanks. I didn't found this information in .net ajax documentation. Now I'm experiencing malfunctions with the accordion control, but I guess its another issue.